# Universal hash with collisions

Tags: hash

I have a homework but I really don´t know where start.

Write a program in Java that implements the two families of universal hash functions we saw in class today .
Both families of functions depend on various parameters , so that Java should use two classes whose constructures receive the appropriate parameters and C should make some kind of structure that contains a pointer to a function.
To test their implementations , use the following sets : U = f0 ; 1; 2; ::: 10008g and D = f0 ; 1; 2; ::: 2052g . Write an application at random choose a function of each type and insert U 500 random number in a table containing the addresses of D. The output of your program should be the number of collisions obtained during insertions using buckets policy to solve collisions.

Can you please tell me how can I start or what should I implement for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the two hash functions you have been given
2. Generate and insert into your hash table, 500 numbers of type U which map to an address of type D. The insertion should also randomly choose a hash function to use for inserting
3. Iterate over your hash table and count the number of buckets containing more than one item of type U